# Accessing and checking the attributes of an object's instance, like a "username" attribute in a "User" object for a login page

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

**I created a class whose parameters are user inputs and the attributes are saved as a dictionary into a file with json, to be re-read by python. Now, I want to be able to access the information in that file(the "username" attribute) from a separate file. If the username matches, then you successfully log in.**

*File Name:* create_user_dataset

```
"""THIS PROGRAM CREATES A USER AND SIMPLY STORES ITS INFO IN A TXT FILE TO BE RE-READ BY PYTHON"""

from pip._vendor.distlib.compat import raw_input
import json
class User():
    '''simulates a user for a social network or pc'''
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, username, location, *interests):
        '''initialize attributes of user class'''
        self.first_name = first_name.title()
        self.last_name = last_name.title()
        self.username = username
        self.location = location.title()
        self.interests = interests


    @classmethod
    def get_userinfo(cls):
        '''creates a variable to store user inputs that correspond to User attributes'''
        first = raw_input("Welcome. PLease Enter Your First Name: ")
        last = raw_input("Please Enter Your Last Name: ")
        user = raw_input("Username: ")
        location = raw_input("What is your location? : ")
        interests = []

        print("List some of your interests (Press 'Q' Key to End Program.)")

        active = True
        while active:
            '''infinite loop that creates elements in a list until user quits'''
            interest = input().strip()
            if interest == 'q':
                active = False
            else:
                interests.append(interest)
                print("Press 'Q' Key to End Program.")
        return cls(first, last, user, location, interests)
        """cls fills in the attributes that would go inside of a given User instance"""


    def to_json(self):
        return json.dumps({"first": self.first_name, "last": self.last_name, "username": self.username,
                           "location": self.location, "interests": self.interests})


    @classmethod            
    def from_json(cls, j):
        dct = json.loads(j)
        return cls(dct["first"], dct["last"], dct["username"], dct["location"], dct["interests"])
```

**The second file simply creates instances of User:**

*File Name:* create_user_frontend

```
"""THIS PROGRAM CREATES INSTANCES OF USER AND STORES THEIR INFO IN A FILE"""
from create_user_dataset import User

def create(user): 
    '''creates an instance of User object'''
    filename = r'''C:\Users\User\Documents\dataset1.txt'''

    with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
        '''writes each attribute of User into a file'''
        f.write(user.get_userinfo().to_json())

user1 = User
create(user1)
```

**All of the previous works perfectly, I just wanted to provide background. The third file is the problem. The problem is that when I create a new file, while importing the file where my instance of User is stored, console just runs the imported file rather than the file itself.**

*File Name:* user_login

```
import create_user_frontend as cu

prompt_username = input("Please enter username: ")

print(cu.user1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code in `create_user_frontend.py` will be executed at the time it is imported:

```
user1 = User
create(user1)
```

If you don't want it to be executed when it is imported, but only if the file itself is run (e.g. by calling `python create_user_frontend.py`) you should change it to this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__:
    user1 = User
    create(user1)
```

---

BTW, this won't fix all of your problems, only the one you asked about.

You still have many problem to handle:

- after this change, `cu.user1` is no longer available
- on the other hand `cu.user1` is actually nothing else but `create_user_dataset.User`, because of the dubious line `user1 = User`
- function `create(user)` just receives he `User` class, so it is pointless for it to receive anything
- you probably want to call `User.get_userinfo()` to actually create a user instance
- you should definitely either change the names of these functions, or their functionality, because the names don't match what they do:

  - `User.get_userinfo` does not *get* user info - it creates a `User` instance
  - `create(user)` neither takes a user instance as argument, nor does it return a new user - it creates a user instance, dumps its contents into json and then throws away the instance in the same line

Comment: Yes! This works. Now how would I create a "login page", that checks the username?

Comment: so how could I make cu.user1 available? Or rather, how could I access the username parameter and check it?

Comment: @GilbertoRoblesSilva I guess you need to implement these functions: `read_user_from_file(filename)` (returnsa a `User`), `write_user_to_filename(filename, user)` (returns nothing), and then use these from your main script, e.g. `user1 = read_user_from_file(filename1)`.